# Modify multiple rows of SQL Server XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml.modify

I have a temp table that contains values I want injected as elements into a SQL Server column. I can do this for one entry using the modify and insert statements. But how can I do this for multiple rows in a table?

Some sample data looks like this:

`SerializedTable`:

```
ID    SerializedXML
-----------------------------------------
7     <Form> <Field1>111</Field1> </Form>
8     <Form> <Field1>112</Field1> </Form>
```

`#TempTable`:

```
ID    FK_ID    Value
--------------------
1     7        120
2     8        124
```

So I need to add a new element to `SerializedXML` with the values in the value column.

So the final table would look like:

`SerializedTable`:

```
ID    SerializedXML
---------------------------------------------------------------
7     <Form> <Field1>111</Field1> <Field2>120</Field2> </Form>
8     <Form> <Field1>112</Field1> <Field2>124</Field2> </Form>
```

The name of the element will be the same for all of the new inserted fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```sql
update s
set SerializedXML.modify('
  insert <Field2>{ sql:column("t.Value") }</Field2>
  after (/Form/Field1)[1] 
')
from SerializedTable s
join TempTable t on s.ID = t.FK_ID
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57d5e/7)